# Bokeh legend can't find field

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I'm plotting a line graph with `bokeh` (never used this library before) in a `Jupyter notebook` and I'm trying to add a legend but I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Code**

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'label' : ['something', 'something']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


trend = figure( tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,save",title="trends")

trend.line(source = df, x ='col1', y = 'col2', line_color="red", legend ='label')

show(p)
```

So far I have tried moving the `legend` field and specifying the `dataframe` name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These seems actually to be a small bug in `figure` when a DataFrame is passed as the `source` argument. In this case the DataFrame is automatically converted to a Bokeh `ColumnDataSource` internally, but it is evidently not happening soon enough. However, the fix is straightforward, since you can create a `ColumnDataSource` yourself:

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file, show

d = {'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4], 'label' : ['something', 'something']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

p = figure( tools="pan,box_zoom,reset,save",title="trends")

source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p.line(source=source, x ='col1', y = 'col2', line_color="red", legend ='label')

show(p)
```

Please file a bug report with this code on the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues).

Comment: Thanks, will report the bug on GitHub!